# Finding unit normal vector to conformally expanding space embedded in codimension 2 manifold in terms of conformal parameter.

Tags: manifolds, riemannian-geometry, conformal-geometry

I have a manifold $M^n$ of dimension $n$ that I'm treating as embedded within an $n+1$ dimensional manifold $N^{n+1}$, $M^{n}\subset N^{n+1}$. Now I also have an $n-1$ dimensional manifold $\Sigma^(n-1)$ $\Sigma^{n-1}\subset M^{n}$. So we have $$\Sigma\subset M\subset N$$

To shake things up a bit up a bit let's say $\Sigma$ grows by a conformal factor $a(t)$ as we go along the normal to $ \Sigma $ in M. Then the inner product on $\Sigma$ changes accordingly, $$<,>_{\Sigma}\rightarrow a(t)^{2}<,>_{\Sigma}$$

I'm trying to find an expression for the unit normal vector to the hypersurface $M\subset N$ in terms of the conformal factor on $\Sigma$.

In case I'm not being clear let me give a simplistic example:

Consider the spaces $S^{1}\subset S^{1}\times\mathbb{R}\subset\mathbb{R}^{3}$. We have the circle embedded in the cylinder then our circle is conformally transformed as we move up or down the cylinder. What is the unit normal vector to $ S^{1}\times\mathbb{R}\ $?

If we choose cylindrical coordinates ($\rho,\phi,z$) aligned with our cylinder then the normal vector is infinitesimally:

$$\overrightarrow{n}=da(z)\hat{\rho}-dz\hat{z} $$

Such that our unit normal is: $$\hat{n}=\frac{\overrightarrow{n}}{|n|}=\frac{da}{\left(da^{2}+dz^{2}\right)^{1/2}}\hat{\rho}-\frac{dz}{\left(da^{2}+dz^{2}\right)^{1/2}}\hat{z}=\frac{da}{dz}\left(\left(\frac{da}{dz}\right)^{2}+1\right)^{-1/2}\hat{\rho}-\left(1+\left(\frac{da}{dz}\right)^{2}\right)^{-1/2}\hat{z}$$

Which can be noticably written as a unit complex vector: $$\hat{z}=e^{-i\theta}=cos(\theta)-isin(\theta)$$
(not to be confused with the former $\hat{z}$)

so that: $$\hat{n}^{\mu}\hat{n}_{\mu}=\hat{z}\bar{\hat{z}}=1$$

for some theta $$\theta=Cos^{-1}\left(\frac{da}{dz}\left(\left(\frac{da}{dz}\right)^{2}+1\right)^{-1/2}\right)$$ where the real and imaginary axis correspond to $\rho$ and $z$ respectively.

This setup makes sense as a check when I think about the normal bundle of $\Sigma$ in our general situation having $SO(2)$ fibers on $N$  (since it's always codimension 2).

I also know that the conformal group of an $(n-1)$ manifold is locally $SO(n,1)$, but I don't see how that comes into play here.

I believe I've done this construction right, and it would seem to apply to the general case as well. Is this correct?

How would I generalize this when the conformal factor (scale parameter) is a function of all of the coordinates $a(x(t)^i)$ on $M$? I'd expect the unit normal vector in $N$ necessarily involve a gradient of the scale factor then?. At the very least I'd like to find a coordinate invariant way of writing this expression in general.

For a little more background, I'm trying to find an expression for the second fundamental form of $M$ in $N$ in this situation, which turns out to be surprisingly complicated.

Comment: Could you please clarify what does it mean for a hypersurface to **grow by a conformal factor** as we go along the normal to this hypersurface?

Comment: @YuriVyatkin   I meant that the inner product on the hypersurface $\Sigma$ can be written as $$\bar{<,>}=a(t)^{2}<,>$$  for some function $a(t)$, and  $t$ is a coordinate corresponding to the dimension normal to $\Sigma$ in $M$.

Comment: @YuriVyatkin For the example I used in the question, it corresponds to the radius of the circle (our $\Sigma$ here) changing by a function of $Z$ as we travel up the cylinder.